# Need help to convert data in an ArrayList to Strings and Pass each of them as String parameters to a function

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Suppose I have an ArrayList 'slist' that returns an arraylist of session id's . 
I want to pass these session ids one by one as Strings to a function 
say , getTranscript(String sessID) // The sessID is the sessionID that is returned from the ArrayList 'slist' .

I have session IDs returned from :- 
ArrayList slist = WgSession.getSessionList(wgname); //Dont worry //about wgname

Now i want to pass 'slist' as Strings to the function getTranscript(String 'whatever is returned from the arraylist'); so i can get the transcript for each sessionID that is present in 'slist'

Please help ,
It would be good if CODE is given ! THANKS !

Comment: Which types of data are session ID's ?

Comment: It's too much to ask us to just give you the code.  Perhaps if you had some code of your own that you had written, we'd be able to meet in the middle.

Comment: ArrayList<String> slist = WgSession.getSessionList(wgname);
                                  
        ArrayList<String> transcripts = new ArrayList<String>();
  String texttranscript=null;
      for (String s : slist) {
   texttranscript += ChatTranscriptManager.getTextTranscriptFromSessionID(s);
         transcripts.add(texttranscript);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getTranscript is void:

```
for (String s : slist) {
     getTranscript(s);
}
```

If getTranscript returns a string and you would like to save it:

```
ArrayList<String> transcripts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : slist) {
     transcripts.add(getTranscript(s));
}
```

Comment: What i was looking for , THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String tmp : slist) {
      //do stuff  
      getTranscript(tmp);
}
```

?